# KeyError: "['C18orf17', 'UHRF1', 'OLR1', 'TBC1D2', 'AXUD1'] not in index"

Tags: python, pandas

I have seen this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406394/pandas-keyerror-columns-not-in-index). But my problem is not that.

I am trying to extract some column of large dataframe:

```
dfx = df1[["THRSP", "SERHL2", "TARP", "ADH1C", "KRT4", 
                 "SORD", "SERHL", 'C18orf17','UHRF1', "CEBPD",
                 'OLR1', 'TBC1D2', 'AXUD1',"TSC22D3",
                 "ADH1A", "VIPR1", "LRFN2", "ANKRD22"]]
```

It throws an error as follows:

```
KeyError: "['C18orf17', 'UHRF1', 'OLR1', 'TBC1D2', 'AXUD1'] not in index"
```

After removing the above columns it started working. fine

```
dfx = df1[["THRSP", "SERHL2", "TARP", "ADH1C", "KRT4", 
                 "SORD", "SERHL", "TSC22D3",
                 "ADH1A", "VIPR1", "LRFN2", "ANKRD22"]]
```

But, I want ignore this error by not considering the column names if not present and consider which overlap. Any help appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) for select only columns with list if exist:

```
L = ["THRSP", "SERHL2", "TARP", "ADH1C", "KRT4", 
      "SORD", "SERHL", 'C18orf17','UHRF1', "CEBPD",
      'OLR1', 'TBC1D2', 'AXUD1',"TSC22D3",
      "ADH1A", "VIPR1", "LRFN2", "ANKRD22"]

dfx = df1[df1.columns.intersection(L, sort=False)]
```

Or filter them in [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html), then need [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with first `:` for select all rows and columns by mask:

```
dfx = df1.loc[:, df1.columns.isin(L)]
```

Comment: I would choose either of the options in this answer but you could also use `reindex` though it isn't as good because it adds the missing columns.  You could drop them with `dropna` but you might be dropping prior existing columns.  `dfx.reindex(columns=L).dropna(axis=1, how='all')`

Comment: @piRSquared - yop, but `reindex` change order of columns, what should not be necessary